# VerticalAlign image position

Tags: html, css

I need to locate that question icon in middle of textarea height.
Vertical align does work.

I have main div `.contorls`, inside my link with question with `float:right` and after that textarea.
How to locate this icon?

```
<div class="control">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

.control{width:700px;height:auto;}
.icon{height:20px;width:20px;}
```

Comment: We need to see some HTML / CSS. I have no idea what your question is... ?

Comment: .control{width:700px;height:auto;}
.icon{height:20px;width:20px; background: #000; display:inline-block; vertical-align:baseline;}

Comment: i use yr styles: http://prntscr.com/4tirwt
don't working :(

Comment: Please clarify. When you say "icon in middle of textarea height" do you mean that the icon is shown within the edges of the textarea or vertically aligned next to the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple way to do it.

Use CSS tables by applying `display: table` to the `.control` parent element and `display: table-cell` to the `.wrapper` child element.  Within `.wrapper`, use `vertical-align: middle` to vertically center the icon element.

CSS tables are pretty well supported by most modern browsers so the solution is fairly robust.

```css
.control {
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.control .wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px; /* optional if needed */
  background-color: tan;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```